# Extract a string in Postgresql and remove null/empty elements

Tags: sql, postgresql

I Need to extract values from string with Postgresql
But for my special scenario - if an element value is null i want to remove it and bring the next element 1 index closer.

```
e.g. 
 assume my string is: "a$$b"
```

If i will use

```
select string_to_array('a$$b','$')
```

The result is:

```
{a,,b}
```

If Im trying

```
SELECT unnest(string_to_array('a__b___d_','_')) EXCEPT SELECT ''
```

It changes the order

```
1.d
2.a
3.b
```

order changes which is bad for me.

I have found a other solution with:

```
select array_remove( string_to_array(a||','||b||','||c,',') , '')
from (
select
split_part('a__b','_',1) a,
split_part('a__b','_',2) b,
split_part('a__b','_',3) c
)  inn
```

Returns

```
{a,b}
```

And then from the Array - i need to extract values by index
e.g. `Extract(ARRAY,2)`

But this one seems to me like an overkill - is there a better or something simpler to use ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `with ordinality` to preserve the index information during unnesting:

```
select a.c
from unnest(string_to_array('a__b___d_','_')) with ordinality as a(c,idx)
where nullif(trim(c), '') is not null
order by idx;
```

If you want that back as an array:

```
select array_agg(a.c order by a.idx)
from unnest(string_to_array('a__b___d_','_')) with ordinality as a(c,idx)
where nullif(trim(c), '') is not null;
```