# Transfer a column into a new Table, also adding a mapping Table in between

Tags: sql, postgresql

I was lazy when I originally created a table where one column could contain multiple email addresses, separated by commas, spaces or returns in the field.

Now I like to create a separate table that holds just the email addresses. This can lead to multiple emails belonging to the same original row, so I also like to have a mapping table that links the one or more email rows to the original rows (I understand that for this 1-to-many case where each email can only belong to one customer, this extra map table is not required, but for the sake of solving the specific challenge behind it I like to keep this map relevant for this question).

There are two challenges for me:

1. How to I write the `SELECT` so that I get multiple rows for the comma separated values? The solution I found is to use `unnest(string_to_array(regexp_replace(TRIM(emails),'[\s,]+',',','g'),','))`. (The `TRIM` is for safety, removing extra spaces around the field, so that I do not end up with empty rows - is there a better way, e.g. by removing empty elems from the array? Searching locates [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54867727/43615), which seems to be needlessly complex for my case, though)
2. When I create the mapping row, I need two ids. How do I get these two values? One I get from inserting new rows based on the original rows, but I also need the original row's id. Which means that when I select the original rows, I need to fetch its id along with the emails - but I do not understand how to keep it around while using the emails for the insertion.

### Example

#### Original data

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test_customers;
CREATE TABLE test_customers (id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, emails TEXT);
INSERT INTO test_customers (emails) VALUES ('a@x.com'), ('b1@x.com,b2@x.com');
SELECT * FROM test_customers;
```

**Table test_customers**

| id | emails |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a@x.com |
| 2 | b1@x.com,b2@x.com |

#### Desired outcome

**The new tables**

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test_emails;
CREATE TABLE test_emails (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  email TEXT UNIQUE
);
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test_map;
CREATE TABLE test_map (
  cust_id SERIAL,
  email_id SERIAL,
  CONSTRAINT fk_customer FOREIGN KEY(cust_id) REFERENCES test_customers(id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_email FOREIGN KEY(email_id) REFERENCES test_emails(id)
);
```

**Table test_customers**

Basically, the email column isn't needed any more (I can simply drop that in the end, a no brainer):

| id |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |

**Table test_emails**

The emails are now here:

| id | email |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a@x.com |
| 2 | b1@x.com |
| 3 | b2@x.com |

**Table test_map**

And this links the emails to the customers:

| cust_id | email_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |

#### My SQL code for converting all rows, so far

```
WITH map_ins AS (
  INSERT INTO test_emails (email)
  SELECT
    id AS cust_id,
    unnest(string_to_array(regexp_replace(TRIM(emails),'[\s,]+',',','g'),','))
    FROM test_customers
  RETURNING id AS email_id, cust_id
)
INSERT INTO test_map (cust_id, email_id) VALUES (cust_id, email_id);
```

This gives an error:

> INSERT has more expressions than target columns

That's where I'm stuck. The first `SELECT` needs to fetch both the id and the emails so that I can return them further down, but if I do that, then how do I omit it in the INSERT where I only want to insert the `email` but not the `id` into the row?

Comment: You do not need the table `test_map` if your goal is to create a 1-to-many (1:m) between `customers` and `emails`. You use `cust_id` in `emails` as FK. That completely fulfills the requirement for  a 1:m relationship. What `table_map` does is set up a m;m relationship between `customer` and `emails`.

Comment: Fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/KHe8qJp2 . Which as Belayer said, assumes test_map's true purpose is handling m:m. Maybe postgres has some magic syntax, but since you need to use the generated id in the association/junction/map table it seems simplest to do it in sequence. Or have the id be an integer hash or something instead that can be reproduced.

Comment: @Belayer Ahhh, my mind was twisted. You're correct. As long as no customer can share the same email, only a 1:m relationship is needed, indeed. I had, however, considered to use the same email table in different tables, and in that case I do need the map (which will then get another column that'll identify in which table it's used). Also, it's an excercise for later cases where I might need a m:m relationship, and I'd rather have an answer for this here as I could not find a related answer on SO for this.

Comment: @ThomasTempelmann On a side note ... kudos. I think this is the only time I've ever seen a question aimed at fixing a flawed design rather than asking how to write some bananas code to work around a flawed design.